# Why "pub build" do not build excatly what "pub serve" is serving?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

Using the current version of [angular.dart.tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/commit/f9c9cd835cf913160e40b27eba17760b19b28a78), Using the Chapter_04

- With "pub serve", the main.dart.js is a 42337 lines file and the example is working fine.
- With "pub build", the main.dart.js is a 22539 lines file and the example is NOT working when  I'm serving it through an http web server.

I have the filling that it's something about the transformers.

My concern here is that, I'm working on a Angular Dart application which is working fine using "pub serve", but when I deploy it through a web application server it's not working.
This web application server will provide services NOT written in Dart on which my client side written in Dart with Angular.dart rely on.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with Angular when minification and dart2js is turned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pub serve` uses `--mode=debug` by default, `pub build` (from console) uses `--mode=release` as default.

<strike>I haven't tried `pub serve --mode=release` but I assume it results in the same output als `pub build`.</strike>
I tried `--mode=release` with `pub serve` but it seems not to have any effect.

Release mode does tree-shaking and minification.

Comment: With "pub build --mode=debug" we got exactly the same result as "pub serve". It doesn't tell me why it's not working on release mode, but it's another question.

Comment: I guess `pub serve --mode=release` was just not implemented because it wouldn't be fast enough to make sense. If you need it you can just use `pub build` and serve the result with any basic web server. `pub serve` is optimized for development and needs to be fast, that doesn't go well with (incremental) rebuild on each file change, tree-shaking and minification.